# What is the best way to sort sql data when it's all in 1 column?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join 2 tables together and seperate a column into multiple columns based on an id tag.

e.g
Table "Name"

```
id | field_number | value |
---|--------------|------ |
1  |     1        | john  |
1  |     2        | murphy|
2  |     1        | mary  |
2  |     2        | murphy|
```

Table "id"

```
id ¦ user
1  ¦ person1
2  ¦ person2
```

Result

```
id ¦ First Name ¦ Last Name ¦ user
 1 ¦    john    ¦ murhpy    ¦ person1
 2 ¦    mary    ¦ murphy    ¦ person2
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT t.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.field_number = 1 THEN s.value END) as first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.field_number = 2 THEN s.value END) as last_name,
       t.user
FROM `id` t
JOIN `name` s
 ON(t.id = s.id)
GROUP BY t.id,t.user
```

Comment: That seems to only display one row of data, is there a way to display all rows like this?